# Как метод класса сделать задачей в Celery?

Tags: python, celery

В Celery до 4-ой версии была экспериментальная поддержка объявления методов класса в качестве задач, а сейчас ее убрали.

Я сейчас работаю с одним старым репозиторием с GitHub, в котором именно метод класса являлся заданием Celery и активно использовал внутри себя ссылки на `self`, т.е. его никак не вывести в статический метод.

Как теперь в Celery 4 решается такая задача, когда нужно именно метод сделать заданием в Celery?

Comment: Скорее всего придется писать новый класс для таска с методом `run`, и туда можно передать сериализированый обьект и с ним работать, либо все таки делать более глубокий рефакторинг

Comment: @Barton, то есть сейчас в Celery 4 нужно писать кастомный таск, наследуя его от `Task`, верно?

Comment: да, или спользовать декоратор http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.task который под катом все равно создает инстанс класса.